# Unable to create a mock object of a class in a different project

Tags: mockito, powermock

I am trying to create a mock object of a class which is in a different project but I am unable to do so.
I have tried mocking it with PowerMock,PowerMockito and EasyMock.
It gives me java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException exception.

In my test method of Class A

```
@Test
public void doTestMethod(){
    XYZ mockXYZ=PowerMock.createMock(XYZ.class);

      Once this is created I have to mock the execute Method inside the XYZ class.
}

my Class XYZ looks like this 
Class XYZ
{

private XYZ(){
some initialization of variables;
}

public parameterizaed constructor(parameters){
}

public void execute(){

}
}
```

This XYZ class in a different project

Comment: can you add the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error was resolved it was basically adding the other project in the pom.xml of my project so that at run time it would load the class that I want.